# CircuiTikZ- Ring oscillator

Tags: circuitikz

I want to draw a ring oscillator, i.e an odd number off logic inverters in a ring. I have some real troubles placing the ring nicely corresponding to the inverters, see attached code. Is there any suggestions how to achieve this?

```
    \begin{center}\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
    (0,3) node[not port,rotate=-360] (mynot1) {}
    (2.2,1.4) node[not port,rotate=-72] (mynot2) {}
    (2,-1.4) node[not port,rotate=-144] (mynot3) {}
    (-2,-2) node[not port,rotate=-206] (mynot4) {}
    (-2.2,1.4) node[not port,rotate=-288] (mynot5) {}
    (mynot1.out) to[bend left] (mynot2.in)
    (mynot2.out) to[bend left] (mynot3.in)
    (mynot3.out) to[bend left] (mynot4.in)
    (mynot4.out) to[bend left] (mynot5.in)
    (mynot5.out) to[bend left] (mynot1.in);
    \end{circuitikz} \end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using polar coordinates would be one way to do it:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (  -0:3) node[not port,rotate= -90] (mynot1) {}
              ( -72:3) node[not port,rotate=-162] (mynot2) {}
              (-144:3) node[not port,rotate=-234] (mynot3) {}
              (-216:3) node[not port,rotate=-306] (mynot4) {}
              (-288:3) node[not port,rotate=-378] (mynot5) {}
              (mynot1.out) to[bend left] (mynot2.in)
              (mynot2.out) to[bend left] (mynot3.in)
              (mynot3.out) to[bend left] (mynot4.in)
              (mynot4.out) to[bend left] (mynot5.in)
              (mynot5.out) to[bend left] (mynot1.in);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

By using the `\foreach` loop macro, we can avod the repeated code:

\documentclass

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt][margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \foreach \i in {0,...,4} {
            \draw (-\i * 72:3) node[not port,rotate=-90 - \i * 72] (mynot\i) {};
        }
        \foreach[remember=\i as \j (initially 4)] \i in {0,...,4} {
            \draw (mynot\j.out) to[bend left] (mynot\i.in);
        }
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Getting a perfect circle is more difficult. One problem is that the `circutikz` not gate node already includes straight line segments that we can't easily get rid of.

If you're not set to use this gate and are willing to trade for the not gate from `pgf`'s `circuits.logic.US` library, things are a little easier. The only issue is that this node's `center` anchor doesn't actually lie in the middle of its `input` and `output` anchors, requiring some more trickery to make sure that all inputs and outputs actually lie on the same cicle.

For this reason, I'm first drawing a fake node that I can measure and then calculate the correct coordinate for each node. I can then use some math to figure out the correct angle and radius for each arc connecting the gates.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[not/.style={circuit logic US,not gate}]
        \newcommand\radius{2}
        \newcommand\ngates{5}

        % draw a hidden not gate so we can measure the distance between its input and output
        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \node[not,anchor=input,transform canvas={scale=0}] at (0, \radius) (dummynot) {};
        \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

        \foreach \i in {1,...,\ngates} {
            \draw let \p0 = (dummynot.output) in        % \x0 is now the "length" of the node, \y0 is the radius
                  (-\i * 360 / \ngates:\y0)             % this is the position on the circle
                  ++(-90 - \i * 360 / \ngates:-\x0 / 2) % this is the offset that makes the input and output lie at the same distance from the center
                  node[not,anchor=input,rotate=-90 - \i * 360 / \ngates] (mynot\i) {};
        }
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\ngates} {
            \draw let \p0 = (mynot\i.output),
                      \p1 = (mynot\i.input),
                      \p2 = (dummynot.output) in
                  (\p0) arc[start angle={atan2(\y0, \x0)},delta angle={2 * atan2(\x2 / 2, \y2) - 360 / \ngates},radius={veclen(\p0)}];
        }
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: 5 gates]
[image: 11 gates]
[image: 4 gates]
[image: 2 gates]
[image: 1 gate]

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Yes, but its still not a "ring", its quite discontinuous

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently messing around with that, but I figured that this version is already an improvement :-)

Comment: @Edzroem Due to the two straight line sticking out of the input and out put of the not gate, it would be very difficult to maintain a *circle* and avoid *corners* at the joining point at the same time.

Comment: Well, here it is. Have fun :-)